How Graham's scan algorithm prepares points to find a convex hull?
I wanted to solve Erect The Fence from LeetCode. That's my code:
const double PI = 3.141592653589793;

double get_angle(const vector<int>& p1, const vector<int>& p2) {
    vector<int> p{ p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1] };

    double angle = atan2(p[1], p[0]);
    angle = angle * 180 / PI;

    if (angle < 0)
        angle = 180 + (180 + angle);

    return angle;
}

static bool comp(const tuple<double, int, int>& k1, const tuple<double, int, int>& k2) {
    if (get<0>(k1) == get<0>(k2)) {
        if (get<2>(k1) == get<2>(k2))
            return get<1>(k1) < get<1>(k2);

        return get<2>(k1) > get<2>(k2);
    }

    return get<0>(k1) < get<0>(k2);
}

vector<vector<int>> outerTrees(vector<vector<int>> trees) {
    if (trees.size() <= 3)
        return trees;

    vector<int>* bottom_left_most_tree = &trees[0];
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < trees.size(); ++i) {
        if (trees[i][1] == (*bottom_left_most_tree)[1] && (trees[i][0] < (*bottom_left_most_tree)[0])
            || (trees[i][1] < (*bottom_left_most_tree)[1])) {
            bottom_left_most_tree = &trees[i];
            idx = i;
        }
    }

    vector<tuple<double, int, int>> forest(trees.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < trees.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == idx) {
            forest[i] = { -1, trees[i][0], trees[i][1] };
            continue;
        }

        double angle = get_angle(*bottom_left_most_tree, trees[i]);
        forest[i] = { angle, trees[i][0], trees[i][1] };
    }

    sort(forest.begin(), forest.end(), comp);

    stack<vector<int>> polygon_vertices;
    polygon_vertices.push(*bottom_left_most_tree);
    polygon_vertices.push({ get<1>(forest[0]), get<2>(forest[0]) });

    auto tree = forest.begin();
    ++tree;

    for (; tree != forest.end(); ++tree) {
        vector<int> mid = polygon_vertices.top();
        polygon_vertices.pop();

        vector<int> prev = polygon_vertices.top();

        polygon_vertices.push(mid);

        vector<int>const& next = { get<1>(*tree), get<2>(*tree) };

        double alpha = get_angle(prev, mid);
        double beta = get_angle(mid, next);

        while (beta < alpha) {
            polygon_vertices.pop();
            mid = polygon_vertices.top();

            polygon_vertices.pop();
            prev = polygon_vertices.top();

            polygon_vertices.push(mid);

            alpha = get_angle(prev, mid);
            beta = get_angle(mid, next);
        }

        polygon_vertices.push(next);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> result(polygon_vertices.size() - 1);
    int i = 0;
    while (polygon_vertices.size() > 1) {
        result[i] = polygon_vertices.top();
        polygon_vertices.pop();

        ++i;
    }

    return result;
}

I thought I'm able to implement Graham Scan algorithm. But after testing the code I'm not sure about one thing. How to sort the points?
As u can see, as starting point I get the most bottom (lowest Y), and if there are many, I get the one with the lowest X (most on left).
The problem with this code is that it sorts points the by angle between starting point and the point itself. Then, if there are many, by highest Y, and if there are many, then it sorts by X (most left).
And that's a problem - because if we have multiple points above starting point (like 90 degress, the same X but different Y), then we first visit the highest point - and then return back to the points with lesser Y. It produces bad results.
But sorting by highest Y is necessary so we won't come to the same problem (e.g. consider two points with the same angle between them itselfs and starting point, but with different Y. We have to visit the one with highest Y, otherwise we can get wrong result).
I thought I need to divide points on two halves by line that connects bottom most and the highest points. Then one half will have clockwise turns, and the another counterclockwise.
But because I haven't see Graham's scan algorithm explanation that behaves like that, I wonder what have I misunderstood? How to sort the points?

input data structure matters,afaik. Oh, and your idea sounds more like a preparation for tesselation.

Using tuples like const tuple<double, int, int> is the wrong kind of lazy. std::tuple (and std::pair) exist to help  with (meta) template programming. In all other cases just declare your own struct. E.g.  vector<int>const& next = { get<1>(*tree), get<2>(*tree) }; is just unreadable.  With a struct it would be unecessary.... and WHY are you using a reference on the lefthand side? Yes (probably by accident ) it will extend the lifetime of the temporary vector, but is not needed

This is one of the issues I have with competitive coding... all kind of half understood "tricks" end up in code

@PepijnKramer The other major issue is that persons tend to overzealously jump right in and write code to solve the "easy" cases, many times knowing full well that the first set of code will not work for the edge/hard cases, but believe just a tweak of the code here or there is all that's needed to get it to work 100%.  Then many times what ends up happening is that vast amounts of the code has to be rewritten, if not thrown away entirely because the original code just had too many holes in it to actually solve the entire problem.  That is what is called "painting yourself into a corner".

@PaulMcKenzie I've seen that happen way too often, specially with the "easy" languages like "Visual Basic" (in the past) and Python nowadays. If it is too easy to get your first draft working people seem to forget all about design ;)

@PaulMcKenzie Solving what you can, then trying to build on it to solve larger cases is a classic problem solving technique (see section "What good is that?"). It's much easier to build from a suboptimal, flawed/partial solution than it is from nothing.

Agree with ggorlen. Often, the easiest way to answer "is this a hard problem?" is by trying to use the naïve technique and see if that gives one answer. If that fails, you know you have a hard problem and can using techniques to isolate the problematic part, solve the remainder, and then perturb the solution to deal with the problem.

@MSalters -- That works in many cases.  But the one case where this technique usually fails (and miserably) is writing some sort of expression parser in a naive way.   If the programmer isn't aware of the formal techniques of writing parsers, they end up writing something naive that actually works for the current set of simple expressions.  Then when it comes time to support just another operation, entire swaths of the code has to be rewritten, or in extreme cases, the entire code has to be rewritten.

A Graham scan should successfully produce a convex hull no matter how you break ties when sorting by angle.
If you're writing the kind of Graham scan that removes redundant points by accepting only left turns, then you should get exactly the same result no matter how you break ties when sorting points.  In fact, in this case only the farthest point at any angle could possibly end up on the convex hull, so you could just get rid of all the other ones.
Your problem requires you to keep redundant points, however, and that kind of Graham scan also accepts proceeding in the same direction in addition to turning left.  In this case, it's important that the points on the hull are visited in the correct order.
Note that this only affects the facets of the hull immediately before and after the starting point, because at all other angles, only the furthest point could possibly be on the hull.
Since you are starting with the smallest point by (y,x) you can sort your points into the desired order using this comparison algorithm for any two points a and b:

If a.y == start.y and b.y == start.y, then the points are on the first (bottom), horizontal segment of the hull.  The point with the smaller x coordinate comes first.  Otherwise
Calculate the angles between the points and start.  If they are different, then the point with the smallest angle comes first.  Otherwise,
The point that is farther away from start comes first.  This will always be the one with the highest y coordinate.

Now, this is how to fix a Graham scan the way you want, but it might not solve all of your problems, because you are using inexact floating point math and atan2 in your comparison function.  Because of rounding errors in your computations, it's possible that points at the same angle could end up being sorted as if they were at different angles, and then the order in which you visit them could be messed up.
You could fix this by being very careful in your comparison function to get exactly the right result.  That's a little tricky, though.  I would really suggest switching to the monotone chain algorithm instead.  This is a lot like a Graham scan, but it doesn't involve angles or numerically unstable computations.

I think there is something missed. If we consider two points a and b, and both of them lies on the same x as the starting point, then we can sort them in two ways, by lowest or by highest y - it depends whether we go from starting point or we are going back to starting point. Maybe did I misunderstood something about how Graham algorithm works?

Unless it's on the first or last segment of the hull, it doesn't matter.  If start=(0,0), a=(0,1) and b=(0,2), then there will be a right turn at a no matter whether it's before or after b, so it will be deleted no matter what.

So there must be something wrong with my implementation, excluding sorting points, because it doesn't work for described test case. I checked, it's not caused by using double (at least in specific test case I used). https://imgur.com/a/4qJfTNc I remove points from stack, when beta is lesser than alpha, because then I can be sure that my polygon won't be convex. What's wrong with my code? Can you help with that?

I don't like that you initially push the same point onto polygon_vertices in two different ways, and then rely on atan2(0,0) to return 0.  That's a domain error, really.  But even though I don't like it, it looks like it works.  You'll have to step through it carefully in your debugger.

Oh, you also forgot to remove the last point if it has a right turn connecting back to the first point.

Ah, yes. I will refer to your first comment. It doesn't matter in Graham scan, but in this Erect the Fence problem it matters, because collinear point will be deleted. Am I right? 1/2 How would you sort the points without using atan2? The slope can be negative, so if I sort by slope, then first I will go to points most on left, then most on right and then the rest. 2/2

Right.  Let (x1,y1) = P1-Pstart and (x2,y2)  = P2-Pstart, then x1*x2+y1*y2 is proportional to the cosine of the difference in their angles, and x1*y2-y1*x2 is proportional to the sine.  You can do these calculations using exact integer arithmetic only, and use the signs of the sin and cos to figure out whether the difference in angle is 0, >0, or <0.

You're not seeing the forest for the trees.
The start problem for Graham's algorithm is that you need one (1) point that's on the convex hull. If there is one point with the lowest Y coordinate, then you can easily prove that it's on the convex hull. But now you're wondering, what if there are two points which have the same lowest Y coordinate?
Take one step back. Why must a point with the lowest Y coordinate lie on the convex hull? Hint: use a proof by contradiction to show it cannot lie in the interior. Now apply this proof to two points sharing the lowest Y coordinate.

I have no idea what proof by contradiction is. But I can imagine that the point with lowest Y (and highest similarly) will never be "inside" points creating convex hull if it's not in convex hull itself. When I consider two (or more) points with the same Y, then every of them can be in convex hull if we allow collinear points. If we don't, then only left most and right most points should be in the convex hull. But in my problem (Erect the Fence), I have to include collinear points, so I think as starting point I can select any of points lying on the lowest Y. I still cant figure out problem.

@Szyszka947: Correct, any point with the lowest Y can be the starting point. They're all located on the convex hull. Of those points, the ones with the lowest and highest X coordinate are the two bottom corners.

I still don't see how it can solve my problem.

@Szyszka947: That's because you haven't yet figured out what your real problem is. It's definitely possible that you've got multiple points on the bottom, or multiple points on another side of the convex hull. The key insight here is that you just note that. As soon as you know that a point lies on the convex hull, you know it's in not in the interior, and that's what the question asks.
